# Probability of no failing bit in first byte

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

If a unit consists of total 3 bytes of memory and each bit has a failure probability of 12.5%, what is the probability that there is no failing bit in the first byte?

(8C3/24C3)*1/8 will give the probability of all failing bits in 1 byte. Using this 1-(8C3/24C3)*1/8 will give probability of no failing bit. it it correct?

Comment: It seems weird that you are telling us about a unit of 3 bytes. There are 8 bits in a byte and that is all you need to know to find the probability. Is there something more to this problem that you are not telling us ?

Comment: Please say what are your thoughts on the problem: what have tried etc.

Comment: @clark: IMHO, she did that.

Comment: @BruceET not to brag, but I think my comment had something to do with it:)

Comment: @clark: Congratulations! Glad someone has succeeded with that.